# Export csv based on specific column

Tags: html, csv, vbscript, asp-classic

Export column data as CSV when a column in HTML is selected. This HTML is  generated by the following `sms.asp` page.

```
 <%Option Explicit%>
<%
Dim strConn, strScriptName

strScriptName = Request.ServerVariables("Script_Name")
' RESPONSE.WRITE strScriptName
strConn = Application("eDSNSMS")

Dim strSQL, boolQuery
strSQL=""

strSQL = Request.QueryString("SQL")
boolQuery = Request.QueryString("boolQuery") 'apa ini

Dim objRS, objConn
set objConn = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set objRS = server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>DB Admin</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .button{
            width:70px;
            }
    </style>
    <script language="Javascript">
    function Submit_Query(){
        var SQL = SQL_Form.SQL.value;
        if (SQL=="") return false;
        window.location="<%=strScriptName%>?boolQuery=True&SQL=" + URLEncoding(SQL);
    }
    function Submit_Execute(){
        var SQL = SQL_Form.SQL.value;
        if (SQL=="") return false;
        if (confirm("Are you sure export to csv file?")){
            window.location="csv.asp?SQL=" + SQL;
        }
    }

    function URLEncoding(inputValue)
    {
    inputValue=escape(inputValue);
    re = /\+/gi;
    return inputValue.replace(re, "%2B");
    }

    var selectedIndex=0;
    function selectedValue(i){
        if (selectedIndex==i){
            document.getElementById("Row_" + selectedIndex).bgColor="#e0e0e0";
            document.getElementById("Row_" + selectedIndex).style.color="black";
            selectedIndex=0;
            return;
        }
        else{
            if (selectedIndex!=0){
                document.getElementById("Row_" + selectedIndex).bgColor="#e0e0e0";
                document.getElementById("Row_" + selectedIndex).style.color="black";
            }
            selectedIndex=i;
            document.getElementById("Row_" + selectedIndex).bgColor="darkblue";
            document.getElementById("Row_" + selectedIndex).style.color="white";

        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body topmargin=0 leftmargin=0 rightmargin=0>
<table width=100% border=0 cellpadding=2 cellspacing=0 bgColor="silver">
<tr style="font-weight:bold;font-size:16pt"><td>Database Administration</td></tr>
</table>
<%
On Error Resume Next

objConn.Open strConn

objConn.BeginTrans 'apa ini
MainProgram


If Err.Number = 0 Then  
    objConn.CommitTrans 
Else
    objConn.RollbackTrans 
    Response.Write "&nbsp;&nbsp;" & Err.Description
End If

%>
</body>
</html>
<%


If Not objRS Is Nothing Then
    If objRS.State=1 Then 
        objRS.close
    End If
    Set objRS=Nothing
End If


If Not objConn Is Nothing Then
    If objConn.State=1 Then
        objConn.close
    End If
    Set objConn=Nothing
End If


 Private Sub MainProgram ()
    <form name="SQL_Form" onSubmit="return false;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight:bold">SQL Statement: </td>
            </tr>
            <tr >
                <td><textarea rows=5 cols=70 name="SQL"><%=Server.HTMLEncode(strSQL)%></textarea><br>
                <input class="button" type=button value="Query" onClick="Submit_Query();">&nbsp;
                <input class="button" type=button value="Export"  onClick="Submit_Execute();">&nbsp;
                <input type=button style="cursor:hand;width:75px" value="Cancel" onClick="window.location='ConsultantMenu.asp'"></td>
            <tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <%
        If strSQL="" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If


        If boolQuery = "True" Then
            Dim intTotalRecord, intTotalFields, intRow
            Dim x,i
            objRS.CursorLocation = 3  'adUseClient 
            objRS.CursorType = 3      'adOpenStatic
            objRS.LockType = 1         'adLockReadOnly 
            objRS.Open strSQL, objConn
            Set objRS.ActiveConnection = Nothing


            intTotalRecord=objRS.RecordCount

            If intTotalRecord=0 Then
                Response.Write "&nbsp;&nbsp;No Record Found."
            Else

                Response.Write "&nbsp;&nbsp;" & intTotalRecord & " Record(s) Found."
                Response.Write "<br><table border=0 cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1 style=""font-size:10pt"">"

                intTotalFields = objRS.Fields.Count - 1 

                Response.Write "<tr>"
                For Each x in objRS.Fields
                   Response.Write "<td class=""outrim"">" & x.Name & "</td>"
                Next
                Response.Write "</tr>"

                objRS.MoveFirst
                intRow=1
                Do Until objRS.EOF

                    Response.Write "<tr class=""Row_Class"" id=""Row_" & intRow & """ bgColor=""#e0e0e0"" onclick=""selectedValue(" & intRow & ")"">"
                    For i=0 to intTotalFields
                        Response.Write "<td nowrap>" & objRS(i) & "&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>"
                    Next
                    Response.Write "</tr>"

                    intRow=intRow+1

                    objRS.MoveNext
                Loop

                Response.Write "</table>"
            End If

        Else
            Dim intTotalAffectRecord
            objConn.Execute strSQL, intTotalAffectRecord
            Response.Write "&nbsp;&nbsp;" & intTotalAffectRecord & " Record(s) affected."
        End If


End Sub

%>
```

[image]

I wanted to let user export their select query to csv files when they click export button, so i create a page call `csv.asp`. But now i just wanted if the user select to mtel column then only the if else statement (mark as 'start here' as comment) work. How can i do this?

```
Dim strConn, strScriptName,strSQL

strConn = Application("eDSNSMS")

strSQL = Request.querystring("SQL")

sub Write_CSV_From_Recordset(RS)
  if RS.EOF then
        exit sub
    end if

    dim RX
    set RX = new RegExp
        RX.Pattern = "\r|\n|,|"""

    dim i
    dim Field
    dim Separator,strRow

    do until RS.EOF
        Separator = ""
        for i = 0 to RS.Fields.Count - 1
            Field = RS.Fields(i).Value & ""
            if RX.Test(Field) then
                Field = """" & Replace(Field, """", """""") & """"
            end if

            'start here
            If Left(Field, 2) = "01" and  InStr(Field, "-") <> 0 Then
                if Len(Field) = 11 Then
                 Field = "6" & Field
                 Field = """" & Replace(Field, "-", "") & """"
                else
                 Field = ""
                end if
            elseif Left(Field, 2) = "01"  and  InStr(Field, "-") = 0 then
                if Len(Field) = 10 Then
                 Field = "6" & Field
                else
                 Field = ""
                end if
            elseif Left(Field, 3) = "011"  and  InStr(Field, "-") <> 0 then
                if Len(Field) = 12 Then
                 Field = "6" & Field
                 Field = """" & Replace(Field, "-", "") & """"
                else
                 Field = ""
                end if
            elseif Left(Field, 3) = "011"  and  InStr(Field, "-") = 0 then
                if Len(Field) = 11 Then
                 Field = "6" & Field
                else
                 Field = ""
                end if
            elseif Left(Field, 2) <> "01" and IsNumeric(Field) = true then
                 Field = ""
            elseif Left(Field, 2) <> "01" and InStr(Field, "-") <> 0 then
                 Field = ""
            end if
            Response.Write Separator & Field
            Separator = ","
        next
        if (Field <> "") then
        Response.Write vbNewLine
        end if
        RS.MoveNext
    loop
end sub

Dim objRS, objConn

set objConn = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.ConnectionString = strConn
objConn.Open
set objRS = server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
objRS.Open strSQL, strConn, 0, 1

Write_CSV_From_Recordset objRS
Response.ContentType = "text/csv"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=export.csv"
%>
```

Comment: I don't fully get what you are asking for, can you be more specific?

Comment: @Jonathan because the system can be ask user to input any select query that can be any table and column..and the export button can export any record that user want..but now i want a specific things do when user select  mtel column from cocust table...

Comment: @Jonathan so how can i code to know the user input column name is same as mtel...so the if else statement can be run

Comment: The question was not asked clearly and was hidden in the long description.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have with this approach is that the user can extract the data they want in any number of ways without you being able to defend against it.

Perhaps your best bet would be to parse the `SELECT` clause and severely limit what can be retrieved by the query in the first place.  A simple method for doing this would be to have an array of allowable fields and only allow the query if *only* those fields are present, or remove fields that do not belong there.

I realise that string handling in Classic ASP is a little more bothersome than ASP.NET, but IMHO it would make for a better and more secure application.

Answer (score -1):

You can track the selection of the column in various ways. You can use a hidden field to track from asp. When the user selects the `mtel` column, set the value of the hidden field for example, to 1. Read this value in the controls statement ( if else according to you) and take decision.

For example, set  the hidden field isColumnSelected value to 1 when you select the column using JavaScript.

- Remember to add the hiddend field in your asp/HTML.
- Read the value of `isColumnSelected` field in asp  and take decision:

Comment: when i only add`<asp:HiddenField ID="isColumnSelected" runat="server" /> ` in the in the csv.asp it come out this error
**Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0400'**

**Expected statement**

<asp:HiddenField ID="isColumnSelected" runat="server" />

Comment: i wonder which place should i put the `<asp:HiddenField ID="isColumnSelected" runat="server" />`

Comment: I think you got the idea where to start searching.You can google on " how to add hidden form field to html ", " How to access hidden form field from asp/HTML" , or how to set HTML hidden field value using javascript. --- hope that helps.

Comment: i have add hidden form field and set it to javascript..but i'm not sure how to track the column name in javascript...may help?

Comment: As @Jan points out Classic ASP and ASP.Net are different technologies.

Comment: @Lankymart hi, thanks for giving a comment..do have any suggestion for this?

Comment: This code is asp.net, which is about as different from asp-classic as Java is from JavaScript.